# /usr/bin/vscodium: line 53: 8741 Segmentation fault VSCODE

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code

I am trying to install vscode/vscodium on an **asahi ARM operating system (On my Macbook Pro M1).** [More about ashai](https://asahilinux.org/2022/03/asahi-linux-alpha-release/)

I've tried installing several repositories like this one: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/visual-studio-code-bin.
Even a Chinese version that is compatible in aarch64: https://www.cxybb.com/article/qq_36154886/109362534

Every time I try to run the program from the terminal with the command `.code` I get the following error:

`/usr/bin/vscodium: line 53:  8741 Segmentation fault      ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE=1 "$ELECTRON" "$CLI" --ms-enable-electron-run-as-node "$@"`

Honestly, I'm pretty sure I've correctly installed the package with the correct version for my computer's architecture but I don't know how I could solve the problem, online there are no results.

Thanks!

Comment: I even tried the non-binary version. Did take couple of minutes to compile everything. The segmentation fault is not the same number though. {code} /usr/bin/vscodium: line 62: 67859 Segmentation fault      ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE=1 "$ELECTRON" "$CLI" --ms-enable-electron-run-as-node "$@" {code}